# Magento 2 Cookie for specific domain without extra dot

Tags: magento2, cookie, multidomain, multi-website, magento-2.2.5

I am trying to set the cookie for the specific domain(as I have multiple websites and I don't want to share them) so for this, I changed the configuration as OOTB Magento provides this feature (`Stores > Configuration > General > Web Default Cookie Settings > Cookie Domain`) and I added my domain and set the Cookie Path `/` and saved the configuration, clear cache, cookies . On the frontend side, I can see all cookie set to the to my domain expect `form_key` which is adding extra .(dot)

[image]

So is this correct way or am I missing something to set the cookie for the specific domain? and another question is

**Why Magento adding . (dot) to only `form_key` cookie?**

Comment: did you find any solution?

Comment: Not really, but you can see the updates from here https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/17323 @Camit1dk

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before worrying about why it happens, you may want to consider whether it's actually a problem for you. It seems to be that having a leading dot shouldn't be affecting cookie behaviour in the browser.

The leading dot means that the cookie is valid for subdomains as well. [RFC 6265 Section 4.1.2.3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6265#section-4.1.2.3) defines this as so modern browsers should ignore leading dots if you're on the base domain.

> For example, if the value of the Domain attribute is
> "example.com", the user agent will include the cookie in the Cookie
> header when making HTTP requests to example.com, [www.example.com](http://www.example.com), and
> [www.corp.example.com](http://www.corp.example.com).  (Note that a leading %x2E ("."), if present,
> is ignored even though that character is not permitted, but a
> trailing %x2E ("."), if present, will cause the user agent to ignore
> the attribute.)

---

**EDIT:**

I've done a little bit of testing and it looks as though Magento wasn't actually sending the cookie domain with a leading dot as the `Set-Cookie` header by default, so this points the issue towards being browser behavious and how it handles the `Set-Cookie` headers.

**Chrome dev tools network inspector**:

[image: Chrome dev tools network inspector]

**Chrome dev tools cookie list**:
[image: Chrome dev tools cookie list]

I suspect that the cookies you seen without the leading dot are from cookies assigned by JS functions, rather than a `Set-Cookie` header.

---

**EDIT 2:**

As you mentioned in the comments below, the <s>JS  function</s> PHP function for the cookie JS [here](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.2-develop/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Element/Js/Cookie.php#L62) does look like it adds the leading dot to the domain when the form_key is instantiated [here](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.2-develop/app/code/Magento/PageCache/view/frontend/web/js/page-cache.js#L79), though any further communications with that form_key have the leading dot stripped in the headers too.

[image: Cookies for form_key from server]

This could be a core bug, or it could be a configuration issue (I'm more inclined to think the former of the two)

Comment: Thanks for the answer :) +1 for info. What if I don't want to share cookie for a subdomain? Is there anyway?

Comment: @KeyurShah judging from the wording of the RFC I'd say it seems to try explain that any cookie assigned to the primary domain can be shared with a subdomain, by default.

Comment: Yes, but what If I don't want to share with a subdomain? Is it possible? Rhys

Comment: Hi @KeyurShah, sorry I misunderstood the first comment! It seems as though you can't exactly stop browsers from doing this. Though for Magento if you're working with sub-domains on an multi-store install you'd likely need to configure your store's cookie domains specifically for each store/sub-domain to work around this.
EDIT: here's a good answer I found on how browsers handle cookies with sub-domains, it may provide some more info for you: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/12412/what-cookie-attacks-are-possible-between-computers-in-related-dns-domains-exa

Comment: Thanks a lot for more info @Rhys, yes, I have multistore with a number of subdomains so to achieve this I changed the cookie domain (from the configuration as I mentioned in the question) and it works expect `form_key` and `PHPSESSID` cookie which addes leading dot that's why I am confused. might be you have some idea on this :)

Comment: I think I might have cracked it... I don't think Magento actually _is_ sending the domain with a leading dot for the cookie. I believe it's the browser itself adding this. I turned off JavaScript in my browser and reloaded a blank Magento 2.3 with the cookie domain set up in the admin area and the headers returned with `domain=magento23.dev` in the Set-Cookie header for the HTML response. 
I believe the ones without the leading dots are being assigned to the browser by JS functions, so not susceptible to the same browser behaviour as when it comes via a header. https://snag.gy/JUT5qa.jpg

Comment: Thanks a ton buddy :) for spending your time. for the `PHPSESSID` I also suspect that it is adding by browser but for the form_key it is added by Magento itself. I debugged the code I found this code what Magento does. https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.2-develop/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Element/Js/Cookie.php#L62

Comment: but above code It is used by Magento javascript when you check the page source you will find the cookie domain under `mage/cookies` and even If remove the leading dot from the code magento generate 2 cookie one is without dot and 1 is with leading dot so I can not add product into the cart :( @Rhys

Comment: Hi, added a little more finding above. I'd say this could be a core bug that you're finding in your situation so maybe you should open a GitHub issue on this...

Comment: ok, I will create a support ticket for this and let you know If I have any further updates.  Thanks :) @Rhys

Comment: As per the discussion I created support ticket and they accepted as bug https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/17323 @Rhys thanks for your efforts

Answer (score 0):

From PHP, if you specify a domain name in setcookie, there is a leading dot. If you do **NOT** specify the domain, there should not be a leading dot.

If you have both cookies set in the browser (same cookie name with and without the leading dot), then you will get buggy behaviour.  For instance, you might update the cookie *without* the leading dot, but then PHP decides to read the out-of-date cookie *with* the leading dot.